# Is it possible to call a jquery function on a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to call a query function call on a variable, but it is not working. Is there any way around this?

```
$(function() {
      $variableName = '#fanpagePanelHeader';
      $(variableName).click( function()
           {
             $("#videoAcco").click();
           }
      );
});
```

Comment: $variableName is your variable, but you're passing something else, variableName, to jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to jQuery, but shouldn't it be:

```
var variableName = '#fanpagePanelHeader';
```

Comment: It is always hard to deal with scripting language straight after java and obj -c :(, Thanks btw!

Comment: No problem :) I'm coming from PHP, so even I'm surprised I spotted it!

Answer (score 4):

Your variable is named `$variableName`, so call the jQuery function on the variable:

```
$($variableName).click(...
```

The dollar sign is a valid character in a variable name but don't think it's jQuery-specific. It's just another character.

Comment: +1. Also, `variableName` is undefined but does not cause an error, and best-practice is to use `var` to declare a variable instead of (inadvertently) using a property on the default `window` object.

Comment: Your answer worked but Cassie's answer was more informative :) +1 thanks